# Get value of custom fields from WooCommerce product variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added custom fields to my product variations with this tutorial: http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/. For example:

```
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'          => 'distributor_price[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'label'       => __( 'Händlerpreis', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Dieser Preis wird nur im Onlineshop für Händler angezeigt.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'distributor_price', true )
    )
    );
```

It works fine, I can add and save values. Now I wanna get these values.

I select all other values like this (for example):

```
    $args = array("post_type" => "product", "posts_per_page" => 999, "orderby" => "title", "order" => "asc");
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
    $sequential_number = 1;
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
        $wc_query->the_post();
        $product_name = get_the_title();
        $product_id = get_the_ID();
        $product_url = get_permalink($product_id);
        $product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
        $variables = $product->get_available_variations();
    ...
    $variables[$i][sku]
    $variables[$i][display_regular_price]
    $variables[$i][attributes][attribute_pa_einheit]
```

Now I wanna know how I can get the custom values. I tried it like this - but it doesn't work:

```
$variables[$i][distributor_price]
```

Do you have any tip for me? Thanks and best regards from Germany.

Martin

Comment: Did you define $i , loop through $variables, when you get the variable_product_id, you can make a get_post_meta($variable_product_id, 'distributor_price'); to get the meta field. More code where ... could be great to help ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help!